# Django: How do I use STATICFILES_FINDERS

Tags: python, django

It seems like default settings given in `STATICFILES_FINDERS` are for looking in the static folder within an app. I am trying to get Django to search within the top-level static (same level as `manage.py`), but it doesn't seem to do that despite defining the `STATIC_ROOT` directory in `settings.py` and doing `collectstatic`. It gets a 404 error when looking for the jQuery file.

How can I change this setting so Django looks inside my top-level static folder?

Here is the jQuery 404 error when I run my site:

```
Django version 1.9.6, using settings 'tictactoe.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[06/Jun/2016 23:04:21] "GET /board/ HTTP/1.1" 200 361
[06/Jun/2016 23:04:21] "GET /static/jquery-2.2.4.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1658
[06/Jun/2016 23:04:21] "GET /static/css/boardcss.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
```

**base.html:**

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'jquery-2.2.4.js' %}">
</script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/boardcss.css' %}">
</head>
<body class="body" style="background-color:#545454">
    <div class='container-fluid'>
               {% block content %}
               {% endblock %}   
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**settings.py:**

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',

]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "board", "static"),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
```

My directory tree:

[image: adsf]

Comment: it's just development, my debug=True

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`STATIC_ROOT` is designed for usage with `collectstatic` command [read docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#static-root). If you want your folder to be discovered you need to add it in to [`STATICFILES_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#staticfiles-dirs)

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "board", "static"),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

**Update**

Answering your question in comments

Rename your `static` folder to `staticfiles` or do `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")`.

I would prefer first one. But you will need to add `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")` instead of `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")` in your STATICFILES_DIRS

Like this

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "board", "static"),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles"),
]
```

Comment: That gives me an error:  The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting